# REST api/postman - Cannot GET /the route Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http, restful-url

I am building a (RESTful) Node.js API, using [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2).

I have nade a `server.js`

```
const express        = require('express');
const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');

const app            = express();

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

I can run my server and see the message :

> We are live on 8080

my `index.js`

```
const noteRoutes = require('./note_routes');

module.exports = function(app, db) {
  noteRoutes(app, db);
  // Other route groups could go here, in the future
};
```

and my `node_routes.js`

```
//create a node
module.exports = function(app, db) {

    app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
        // You'll create your note here.
        res.send('Hello')
    });

};
```

`index.js` and `node_routes.js` are both inside `app\routes\`

I have also downloaded the post man app, to make simple requests

and I get the error

> Cannot POST /notes

[image]

what am I doing wrong??
I can not figure it out!

Comment: try to import index.js in server.js

Comment: Add this one in server.js. require('./app/routes')(app, {});

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `server.js`

You are missing `require('./app/routes')(app, {});`

Should be:

```
require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```